# XSLT to extract text from mixed content?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Imagine I have the following XML:

```xml
<schools>
  <school>
    <description>Helpful description</description>
  </school>
  <school>
    <description>Another <important>really important</important> description</description>
  </school>
  <school>
    <description><important>WARNING</important> this is stupid</description>
  </school>
</schools>
```

I want to get the whole description element as text like

```
Helpful description
Another really important description
WARNING this is stupid
```

I'm able to get the `text()` before the first occurence of `<important/>`, but not after. I've tried something like this.

```xml
    <xsl:template match="description" mode="important_recursive">
        <xsl:value-of select="node()/preceding-sibling::text()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="important" mode="important_recursive"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="important" mode="important_recursive">
        <span><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></span>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You say "as text" but your code shows a `span`. Please show the exact, complete result you want to get (as code).

Comment: The built-in templates also copy text nodes through so it is not clear at which point you decided you need to take any complicated effort to get the text content, it should get output without writing templates.

Answer (score 2):

The string-value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes. To get the result you show (as text), you can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/schools">
    <xsl:for-each select="school">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@MartinHonnen mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049474/xslt-xpath-recursivly-convert-mixed-content-to-test#comment123829202_70049474), an empty transformation,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will output the text via the built-in templates:

```
  
    Helpful description
  
  
    Another really important description
  
  
    WARNING this is stupid
```

If you want to eliminate the spurious white space, [see @michael.hor257's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049601/290085), or use `xsl:strip-space` with a simple template matching `description` to place line breaks where desired without a loop,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the requested text output:

```
Helpful description
Another really important description
WARNING this is stupid
```